# TableView selection not visible and error on double click in macOS app

Tags: swiftui

just this small table. I try to make items selectable. But I can't see, which row is selected and if I select the same row again, the app goes down with error: duplicate entry.

```
    @FetchRequest var contacts: FetchedResults<Contacts>
    
    @State private var selectedContact = Set<Contacts.ID>()
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(contacts, selection: $selectedContact, sortOrder: $contacts.sortDescriptors) {
            TableColumn("company", value: \.company) { contact in
                Text(contact.company!)
            }
            TableColumn("name", value:\.lastName) { contact in
                ContactNameView(contact: contact)
            }
            TableColumn("street", value: \.street) { contact in
                Text(contact.street!)
            }
            TableColumn("zip", value: \.zip) { contact in
                Text(contact.zip!)
            }
            .width(50)
        }
        .tableStyle(.bordered(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
        .toolbar {
            Button {
                print("goggo")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }

        }
        Text("\(selectedContact.count)")
    }
```

I think, the problem is on declaring `selectedContact`.

btw. counter on bottom increases on selection, so selecting itself seems to work.

Comment: Is this a macOS app?

Comment: Sorry for this missing information: yes it is.